# How to make control accessible from every class?

Tags: c#, controls

Like the title says :P Let's say I've got 10 classes and I can easily access one textBox.
If I wanted to make a global integer, I've used static. How to do something like that with control?
Thanks

Comment: You can make any type static, even controls. It's a very bad design though. Why do you want to do tha?

Comment: I want to have 1 richTextBox for logging, I can't use Console coz Im working with frames :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a static class a define *that* control like a static member of that class

```
public static class SharedResources
{
    public static UserControl mySharedControl = ...
}
```

After use this control inside code, like

```
SharedResources.mySharedControl
```

Can define also a static *property* instead of *field* naturally.